# How to build render array for image with custom link without using field_view_value()

Tags: media, entities, theming

In a custom module i implemented code to display a image which links to a custom destination. I got it working by building a render array with field_view_value():

**Code snippet I:**

```
$link = 'http://example.com';
$node = node_load($nid);
$image = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image');
$output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_image', $image[0], array(
  'type' => 'image',
  'settings' => array(
    'image_style' => 'thumbnail',
    'image_link' => 'content',
  ),
));
$output[0]['#path']['path'] = $link;
```

But since i have to use for some reason entity_metadata_wrapper() instead of field_view_value() to retrieve the values, i wrote following code:

**Code snippet II:**

```
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $reference);
$link = $node_wrapper->field_image[0]->value();
$output = array(
  'type' => 'image',
  '#theme' => 'image_style',
  '#path' => $link,
  '#style_name' => 'thumbnail',
      'settings' => array(
      'image_style' => 'thumbnail',
      'image_link' => 'content',
    ),
);
$output['#path']['path'] = $link;
```

In this code, the image is shown but the link is not working. As you can see in the screenshots below, the render array generated differs in both snippets. What am i doing wrong in snippet II? How can i achieve the same array structure as in snippet I? Don't know if it is important to mention: Field 'field_image' is a file field provided by the file_entity module.

Using code snippet I:

[image: Content of render array I]

Using code snippet II:

[image: Content of render array II]

Comment: `type` should be `#type` in your second example...

Comment: I did forget to mention that there is the warning "Warning: Illegal string offset 'path'". This error occurs also with '#type' and the link isn't working. There'S something wrong about my '$output['#path']['path'] = $link;'